Why does react code classclass name not working
I using VS code to coding react and i install all necesserary extention but classname command not working "className='text-red-500'"  why isn't working
I also install tailwind extention but still not working.
How can i fix those problem

Ensure tailwind is installed properly by checking package.json file. And also make sure to configure the tailwind.config.js file in your root directory. Refer - Follow this Docs.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You are using tailwind css in react project.Here are the below fixes :
1.Ensure that tailwind css is properly installed (you can check package.json and make sure tailwind.config.js is properly configured in the root directory of your project.
2.Check below lines are added in your App.css or index.css :
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

Please let me know if you still face any issue.
